# Enlarge region/features in shapefile

Tags: qgis, cartography, scale, zoom

I'm completely new to QGIS.

I have a shapefile over the counties in Denmark (see [here for what the shape file looks like](http://biostatistics.dk/rMaps/index.html)). The counties around Copenhagen are rather small and I'd like to add an enlarged/"zoomed in" mini map to make it easier to distinguish between the counties. Thus, both the original counties and the "zoomed in" counties could be linked with the same name to make it easy to see the information in the counties. I know this will produce a map that is not geographically correct, but it will be used to convey information.

I have installed the plugin that allows me to scale a set of selected features but then the remaining regions/features of the map disappeared.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you edit your question to describe the output format you're trying to create? Is that link the actual current output? What you're trying to create is known as an inset map, and you don't actually want to modify your data to do it, but rather create a whole new view/map at a different scale.

Comment: And I shall call it *mini map*... I believe what you are asking for is called an *inset*. I suggest you change your question to *how to add an inset in QGIS*, that might get a little more of the appropriate attention. Have a look at this link first http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Overview-inset-map-in-map-composer-td4135165.html